# Using inheritance and parameters at the same time in t4

Tags: visual-studio, t4

I am using t4 (text templates) to generate emails and would like a common base class for my templates.  To do this, I create an email base template and have all my email templates inherit from it.  Like so:

The base template:

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
```

The derived template:

```
<#@ template language="C#" inherits="BaseTemplate" #>
<#@ parameter name="Param" type="System.String" #>
Template! Param=<#= Param #>
```

Note the parameter in the derived template.  When this is present, it causes the template to have an Initialize method.  And, because the the derived template derives from a base template, the declaration of the Initialize method in the derived template uses the keyword "override".  However, there is no Initialize method on the base template.  This causes an error:

```
'Template.Initialize()': no suitable method found to override
```

I can work around this by declaring a dummy parameter in the base template:

```
<#@ template language="C#" #>
<#@ parameter name="DummyParam" type="System.String" #>
```

Which causes an Initialize method to be generated in the base template, from which the derived template may override.

My questions is, am I missing something?  Having to add a dummy parameter to pacify the compiler make it seem like I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: As the generated classes are partial you can inject the initialize method into the base template from a companion .cs file using partial.